# Origin of "booty", meaning buttocks

Tags: etymology

According to [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=booty&allowed_in_frame=0) the word *booty* is used to describe the female form as a sex object. It says the word is black slang from the 1920s. The definition is placed in the entry for *booty* meaning treasure.

My understanding is that *booty* means *buttocks*, as explained at [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/booty).

Which slang meaning came first? Buttocks or the female form as a sex object? Also, can anyone explain the jump from *treasure* to *buttocks*?

Comment: Of course, if pronounced as written, it refers to stolen treasure. If pronounced as 'boo-tay', _that_ is some treasure. Cf. 'naked': nay-kid vs nehkkid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Sex Slang*](http://books.google.fi/books?id=ORmeNXr1J2sC&pg=PA18&dq=booty%20slang&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-uDqUNHKDaX64QSf1IDQBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=booty%20slang&f=false) (2007) by Tom Dalzell and Terry Victor says:

> **booty; bootie** *noun*
>
> **1. the buttocks** *US*, 1928
>
> - He's Cyndi Lauper's boyfriend, so no skin search. Cyndi ouldn't want us looking up his boodie. - James Elroy, *Suicide Hill* 1986
>
> **2. the vagina** *US, 1925*
>
> - I've got a body as well as a booty. - Partlet, *Booty Snatchers* 1979

(*The Concise New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English* (2007) by Eric Partridge, Tom Dalzell and Terry Victor gives a subset of this same definition.)

The *OED* expands on these same two definitions, but with a wider gap in earliest use:

> 1. Sexual intercourse; a person (esp. a woman) regarded as an object of sexual ambition or desire. Also (occas.): the female genitals. Cf. ass n.2 1b [sexual gratification. Also, a woman or women, regarded as an object affording this.].
>
> 1926   C. Van Vechten *Nigger Heaven* ii. iii. 215   Now..that you've gone white, do you really want..pinks for boody?

And:

> 2. The buttocks.
> Prob. the earlier sense, esp. given the similar sense development of ass n.2, pussy n. 3, etc.
>
> 1959   F. L. Brown *Trumbull Park* 363   Getting kicked in the booty would be mighty discouraging too.

Their etymology is:

> Probably an altered form of botty n.; compare batty n.2 Perhaps influenced (especially in sense 1) by booty n.1 [Plunder, gain, etc.]

Answer (score 7):

The OED suggests that, in this sense, *booty* might be a variant of *botty*, which in turn is a reduced form of *bottom*. If so, the fact that it has the same spelling as the word meaning ‘plunder’ is a coincidence.

Comment: Even if originally the *booty/treasure* link was just coincidence, that must surely be what people have in mind when they say ["shake your booty maker"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22shake+your+booty+maker%22&oq=%22shake+your+booty+maker%22&aqs=chrome.0.57j60l2.1070&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). It's invariably used in the context of flaunting that (attractive, potentially monetisable) asset.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I have never heard 'booty maker' as a thing, so it is surprising to me to see so many google hits. What about a maker of the 'booty' kind is so special? Does it make booties? (Like baby booties, little knit socks for babies?) There's a baby shower coming up and I don't want to make a faux pas.

Comment: A variant of *botty* seems unlikely if the origin is in AAVE. AmE doesn't use that word as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 5):

The term *booty* (buttocks, bottom, whatever) used (usually in the collective sense) to refer to a woman or women in general as sexual objects is a form of [*synecdoche*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/synecdoche):

> A figure of speech in which a part is used for the whole (as hand for sailor), the whole for a part (as the law for police officer), the specific for the general (as cutthroat for assassin), the general for the specific (as thief for pickpocket), or the material for the thing made from it (as steel for sword).

It's the equivalent of referring to *ass* or *pussy* as a stand-in for woman-as-sexual-object. You hear this usage all the time.

Answer (score 1):

The British refer to a car's trunk as the boot. The OED entry for boot is "3 British An enclosed space at the back of a car for carrying luggage or other goods."

In the car designs of the early 1900s onward, the attractive boots of cars did remind one of bums, human or other animal such as horses.

A related term is "dicky" which the OED states is "2 dated, chiefly British A folding outside seat at the back of a vehicle."

It didn't take a very old schoolboy to put 2 and 2 together.  They wouldn't learn the term misogyny for several more years.

Comment: I can see how you have extrapolated from car parts to human parts, taking a schoolboy as the vector, but how do you get the British-English uses to hop the pond to become primarily US slang, which has only lately come back to Blighty through the medium of popular music?

Answer (score 0):

Many scholars believe that Black English Vernacular has its roots in Caribbean creoles. If this is the case, we have to factor in the fact that the word in Jamaican creole is "batty".