# Does "shake his booty" mean "shake his butt"? And does it make it more attractive?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, idioms

I seem to see the phrase "shake his booty" being used to say something is good and attractive.  But does it mean "shake his butt"?  And if they are the same, why does "shake his butt" seem a somewhat distasteful action, but "shake his booty" all of a sudden becomes somewhat glamorous?

Comment: Perhaps, you prefer "*twerk your booty*"?

Comment: No, they do not mean the same, although _butt_ and _booty_ both refer to the buttocks. Shaking your butt in general means just what it says: it is quite literal. Shaking your booty, on the other hand, specifically refers to a particular kind of buttock-shaking, namely _dancing_. A celebrity shaking their booty in a club is a celebrity dancing in a club. A celebrity shaking their butt in a club is just a celebrity looking a bit odd in a club, shaking his or her posterior about in some way or other.

Comment: Don't forget that *glamorous* itself conveys the implication of sex appeal. As for whether that makes it more attractive, beauty, as the saying goes, is in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 4):

"Neither is glamorous!  "Booty" is [American slang for buttocks](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=booty) but almost universally refers to that of a woman.  "Butt" is also slang for "buttocks" but does not imply gender.  Moreover, "booty" has overt sexual overtones (and is, in fact, slang for having sex in some cases), whereas "butt" is not.  (A parent might refer to his/her child's butt, but never the child's booty.)  You may be hearing the term "booty" in pop music lyrics or even some forms of pop journalism, but it is not considered a professional, polite, or glamorous word.

As far as I know, the origin of the term is int he term for a pirate's treasure, called his "booty".  The metaphoric link is to a woman's "treasure", I think.

Comment: I saw the phrase today, when I searched for where to ski in Colorado, in http://news.travel.aol.com/2010/11/18/10-best-colorado-ski-resorts/ where it says about Aspen: "Be sure to check out: The nightlife; there's no telling which celebrity might be shaking his or her booty on the dance floor."

Comment: Yes, it has begun to enter colloquial and informal English usage, especially that referring to nightlife, young people frolicking, etc.  So I suppose that might make it "glamorous" but it's most definitely not considered proper or professional or formal English.

Comment: You might say neither is *inherently* glamorous. The term has the same relation to glamour that, say, "shoe" does. A shoe can be glamorous, or not, but it depends on the shoe and the context. Certainly, Scarlett Johansson shaking her booty at an exclusive nightclub is a deal more glamorous than the character [Wendy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_50AduGvQAU) from *Breaking Bad* doing the same thing at a cheap motel.

Comment: [The gods who speak through our latter-day delphic oracle take some issue with the ‘almost universally refers to a woman’ portion of your statement.](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=shaking+his+booty&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest) What you have written may have once been true, but amongst the younger generation, it certainly no longer holds. Welcome to the 21ˢᵗ century, and the Brave New Millennium it heralds!

Comment: Relevant links: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96402/origin-of-booty-meaning-buttocks, http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=booty. It could be coincidence that 'booty' and 'butt' sound similar.

Answer (score 1):

"Booty" is a word for a person's rear end from the [African American Vernacular English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English) dialect. I believe it probably first entered wider usage through disco music, particularly in the phrase ["Shake your booty"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%28Shake,_Shake,_Shake%29_Shake_Your_Booty).

While it is a fairly normal word in AAVE, when used outside of AAVE it is typically used in a dance or other semi-sexualized context. So in interpreting this word, you have to pay close attention to what dialect is being used.